# How to properly write a helper method in C++ to return a pointer of a class

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value

I am new in C++, I try to write a helper method to return a pointer of a class which will be used in another private method. For example:

```
void MyObject::myFirstMethod();
{
    int index = a function to get a next;
    MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* oneSubObjOfMyObject = getOneSubObjOfListOfSubObj(index)
    oneSubObjOfMyObject->useObj();
    ...
}


MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* MyObject::getOneSubObjOfListOfSubObj(int index)
{
    //std::vector<MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject*> m_VectorOfSubObj
    for (MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* aSubObj : m_VectorOfSubObj)
    {
        if (aSubObj->getIndex() == index)
        {
            return aSubObj;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

At moment this way works, but I am thinking return in the middle of the function might not be a good idea.
normally previous when I write Objective C code, I will do something like

```
- (NSDictionary*)getDic:(Something*)something
{
    NSDictionary *tempDic = nil;
    for (NSDictionary *aDic in anArrayOfDic)
    {
        if([[aDic ObjectForKey:@"aKey"] isEqual: something])
        {
            tempDic = aDic;
        }
    }
    return tempDic;
}
```

But in the C++ case, if I do

```
    MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* MyObject::getOneSubObjOfListOfSubObj(int index)
    {
        MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* tempOneSubObjOfMyObject = NULL;
        for (MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* aSubObj : m_VectorOfSubObj)
        {
            if (aSubObj->getIndex() == index
            {
                tempOneSubObjOfMyObject = aSubObj;
            }
        }
        return tempOneSubObjOfMyObject;
    }
```

I found that later on when I call `oneSubObjOfMyObject->useObj();` `oneSubObjOfMyObject` is complained `BAD ACCESS`.
I was thinking it might be because of `tempOneSubObjOfMyObject` is out of scope, therefore, the `oneSubObjOfMyObject` pointer disappear too.

So my question is, I am wondering if this is a correct way to write a helper function in C++, 
And if there is a proper way I could set up a temp variable in the fucntion and avoid return in the middle of the function. (side note, I know I could use new keyword to have a new object which will be kept in stack. but actually I don't think it is a correct way.. please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: you can't return two types like that: `void MyObject::OneSubObjOfMyObject* MyObject::getOne...`. Typo?

Comment: Either way should work. Are you sure it's not returning NULL because it didn't find the subobject?

Comment: `return` in the middle of the function _is_ a good idea in C++. If you don't need to look further, don't go further, just return. For non-one-liners, I use it more than 50% of the time; it helps understanding, decreases nesting level and might be faster in some cases. So just.. use it.

Comment: There are many errors (typos?) so your example would not even compile, but the general idea should work, provided that index is passed such that null is never returned. Did you try stepping with a debugger?

Comment: If you declared getOneSubObjOfListOfSubObj as a function returning a reference (&) instead of a pointer (*) then you might get an error as the local veriable goes out of scope